# React.js how to register multiple routes in routes file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm very new to `React.js`.

I'm trying to build a very simple app with React router.

[image]

When some one hit the login button it should route to component **Inside.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styles from "./welcome.css";
import {Router,browserHistory } from 'react-router';
class Welcome extends Component {

  onClick(){
    // alert("Hello World!")
    browserHistory.push('/Inside')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="main">
        <div id="welcome">
        <div>
        <input type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="password" />
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />Remember me
        </div>
        <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.onClick}>Login</button>
        </div>
          
          
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Welcome;
```

Right now I don't want to use **Redux** and **Middle-ware**  to handle the authentication. I just only need to route it to the `Inside.js` component.

This is my **Routes.js** here how I define my `/Inside` router path.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Route,IndexRoute} from 'react-router';

import App from './components/App/App';
import Welcome from './components/Welcome/welcome';
import Inside from './components/Inside/inside';


export default(
    <Route path={'/'} component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Welcome}/>
    </Route>
    // <Route path={'/Inside'} component={Inside}>
    // </Route>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine routes as

```
<Route>
    <Route component={App}>
        <Route path='/' component={Welcome} />
        <Route path='Inside' component={Inside} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
```

Answer (score 1):

For routing in React JS apps, I prefer to use `react-router-dom`, its handy, easy to use and you can use the same concepts for routing in React native apps as well.

Node module : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom

Getting up and running guide : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Hope this helps, cheers :)

Comment: Thanks! =) I'll go through it.